# Should we actively try to attract more women to User Interface?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the Users list (http://ui.stackexchange.com/users), the entire first page consists exclusively of men. That's not at all representative of the real UI design industry, where it's much more evenly split. If this were StackOverflow, I wouldn't be surprised, but as a UI design community, it concerns me that we apparently haven't managed to attract much activity from female users.

Should we care or am I overreacting?

Comment: I wonder if I should tag this with "feature request" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skewed demographics means your community is relying *too much* on the Area 51 crowd derived from the Stack Overflow trilogy; that you are **not** going out and promoting your site enough within your industry.

[**A Recipe to Promote your Site**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Usually, efforts to promote to a specific group in that manner are very off-putting and will have the exact opposite results.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Some good tips there.