# What options do we have to promote the site and grow its user base?

Tags: discussion, promotion

In response to [Robert Cartaino's answer to another question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/should-we-actively-try-to-attract-more-women-to-user-interface/84#84), we should talk about this: **what can we do to further grow the site?** Robert's blog post gives some great tips, specifically around how to organise the community in order to ensure people can contribute. What are some ideas here?

- Do any of us know anyone with reach whom we can contact to help promote StackExchange UI?
- Are any members going to any conferences related to UI/UX in the near future?
- Do any of us operate businesses that we can use as a platform to advertise on?
- What UI communities are there out there that we could approach and ask to participate?

Also, how can we tell what our growth rate is and whether it's increasing or decreasing?
Should we endeavour to fill the site with questions for the sake of questions in order to increase our volume and attract more activity?

Feel free to suggest more discussion questions (or add them to the question). This question is intended as inspiration/brainstorm material so we can get started. If we decide on anything specific, I suggest we create a new question for that topic and move from there.

Edit: Looking at [the page for StackExchange UI at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface), I'm seeing some interesting stats:

- only **8.2%** fulfilled their commitment to be active on the site, although **79%** signed up for the beta
- only 55% of the people following the site have signed up for the beta

Is this typical for beta StackExchange sites or should we do something to engage those users in the site? What's keeping them from participating?

Comment: You asked a bunch of good questions. It might be better to split the post into separate questions so each can be discussed individually.

Comment: Good call. Done.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, how can we tell what our growth rate is and whether it's increasing or decreasing?

Keep an eye on the views / day in the right column. It's been hovering between 1100 and 1200. I'd like to see it trend upward.

Also, you can gauge how many people have participated by looking at the [badges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges) page. The Student, Teacher, and Supporter badges are probably the most important. They tell us to how many people have asked, answered, and voted, respectively.

We can see where we stand relative to the other sites at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Thanks for that. I wonder what a "healthy" views/day number is?

Comment: @Rahul check out this link: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: woohoo! we're at over 1300 views/day!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Area51 can send a reminder email to those who haven't fulfilled their commitments?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to send a one-time email to all followers + committers + participants when we reach some threshold (e.g., 300 questions) touting how much progress the site has made.

Comment: It would be nice if StackExchange offered tools so that moderators of sites could do this themselves.