# Do any of us know anyone with reach whom we can contact to help promote StackExchange UI?

Tags: discussion, promotion

Regarding promoting the site and [the various ways to go about doing that](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/what-options-do-we-have-to-promote-the-site-and-grow-its-user-base), are there any members of the UI industry whom we should approach for participation in StackExchagne UI? Do any of us know any of these people? I'm thinking not just of the Jeff Atwoods and Joel Spolsky's of UI, but of the Jon Skeets and Marc Gravells: people who might not be rock stars but *are* significant contributors to the field.

Let's post answers if we know someone and then someone else (possibly the same person) who wants to get in touch with that person can comment. It might be useful to describe the person so we know who they are and also what contribution they could make to our community.

Answer (score 6):

I sent an email a couple of weeks ago to Don Norman, who I've had a few email exchanges with in the past, acknowledging that this is not his area, but also asking him to pass it on to Jakob Nielson, Tog and the rest of the NNG. He had a look and agreed that it was a good thing to be doing, and passed it on.

Comment: whybird, that's totally sweet!

Comment: also, I had a brief email exchange with Jennifer Cardello of the Neilsen Norman Group -- http://www.nngroup.com/about/people/cardello.html -- I referred her to this site as well.

Answer (score 5):

I contacted Michael Angeles, the UX designer of Balsamiq Mockups. He runs Konigi, a neat site that links to various tools and apps for UX designers. He wrote a blog post about StackExchange UI: http://konigi.com/notebook/user-interface-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2):

I run a user group in the UK http:\www.nxtgenug.net, probably the most active in the UK, with a few thousand registrants... with 7 locations across the UK..... WIll promote there...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we start a Twitter account that automatically tweets the latest questions? All we need to do is create an account and then set up [TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/). Then we can promote the account.

Comment: I say go for it :-)

Comment: Hmm. I looked for a feed for new questions and there isn't one. Only the front page has a feed and the questions there aren't necessarily new.

Comment: It seems that there is a secret feed for all questions.  See the discussion on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-all-new-questions